# SQL - delete rows where multiple columns have either null or zero value

Tags: sql, sql-delete, isnull

i have a problem with this sql, it says its a syntax problem near DELETE but can't manage to find it, HELP PLS

It's my first time trying to use the DELETE function so not sure how to do it

```
SELECT 
DE.ContactID AS ContactID,
DE.[First Name] AS [First Name],
DE.[Last Name] AS [Last Name],
DE.Email AS Email,

CASE WHEN bu.ContactId IS NULL 
               THEN '0'
               ELSE '1'
END AS Business,

CASE WHEN des.ContactId IS NULL 
               THEN '0'
               ELSE '1'
END AS Design,

CASE WHEN he.ContactId IS NULL 
               THEN '0'
               ELSE '1'
END AS Health,

CASE WHEN ho.ContactId IS NULL 
               THEN '0'
               ELSE '1'
END AS Hospitality,

DELETE 
FROM [IOW Registered - All workshops]
WHERE (Business IS NULL OR Business = 0) 
                AND (Design IS NULL OR Design = 0) 
                AND (Health IS NULL OR Health = 0)
                AND (Hospitality IS NULL OR Hospitality = 0)

FROM [Domestic SCH] DE 
LEFT JOIN Business bu ON DE.ContactId = bu.ContactId
LEFT JOIN Design des ON DE.ContactId = des.ContactId
LEFT JOIN Health he ON DE.ContactId = he.ContactId
LEFT JOIN Hospo ho ON DE.ContactId = ho.ContactId
```

Comment: You appear to have a delete statement embedded within an outer select.  Please let us know what you are trying to do here.

Answer (score 0):

First write the select statement to get all of the records that you want to delete.  Run it and make sure it is working.

Then make the above select statement only select the ID of the records you want to delete. For example:

```
Select domesticTableID from domesticTable where Design IS NULL or Design = 0
```

Then in your delete statement, put the above select statement in the where clause:

```
Delete from domensticTable where domesticTableID in (Select domesticTableID from domesticTable where Design IS NULL or Design = 0)
```

If you can not figure it all out, post the select statement that returns the records that you want to delete.